# AWS EC2 Instance without private ip (windows)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am starting new instances via a launch configuration where userdata is specified. This data only needs to download a configuration file from S3. The instance is launched with an IAM role that has full S3 rights.

I can confirm that the script does work, if I create the instances with public ip's everything is gravy. However if there is no public ip, it just hangs. I can use a jump box and remote into the box, the user script is there, if I run it, it just hangs.

I have no need for these machines (web servers) to have public ip's as they are behind an ELB and Route 53.

Comment: Oops, the actual question is how to get an instance to access s3 using the iam role without a public ip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your instances have no public-IP and no route to the public Internet you could consider using a VPC endpoint to reach S3:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/

Comment: Thank you! My security group is open for outgoing traffic. I would think S3 should still be accessible?

Comment: Thanks again. I followed the link, setup up the endpoint and voila, it works as it should. I now understand the aws networking concepts a bit more.